# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

I get an error when I try to insert a `role`. I have found some solutions of this issue, but they do not solve my problem:

- [Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063652/integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row)
- [Laravel SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494982/laravel-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-upda)

I am trying to get `id` from `roles` table into `roleID` column of `user_roles` table. Here I am using [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) of Laravel 5.2.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $role = [];
    $role['role'] = $request->input('role');

    $data= Role::create($role);
    $id= $data->id;
    DB::table('user_roles')->insert([
    'roleID' => $id
    ]);
   //return $data;
    return redirect(route('allRole'));
}
```

When I insert any role then it inserts new data in the `roles` table but I am not getting `roleID` in `user_roles` table. I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`amarjobs`.`user_roles`, CONSTRAINT `fkuserRolesuserID` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
(SQL: insert into `user_roles` (`roleID`) values (14))
```

Where is the problem I have done?

Comment: are you trying to assign roles to User ? and what package you are using ?

Comment: I did not used any package.I am trying to do make acl(access control list).Yes, now i am trying to roles for user.

Comment: can you mention you User, Role DB structure and model relationships ? So I can guide you accordingly

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud What is the db structure for `user_roles` table? I guess it has an `user_id` column & it has some foreign key constraint & here you aren't passing any `user_id` value `DB::table('user_roles')->insert([ 'roleID' => $id ]);`

Comment: @Qazi here is relational view http://prntscr.com/auhcxc

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA you can see the db structure here http://prntscr.com/auhfc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see your `user_roles` table required `userID` column & you aren't passing the field while inserting that's what generating the error.

```
DB::table('user_roles')->insert([
    'roleID' => $id,
    'userID' => $userId, //pass your userID here
]);
```

Also I like to mention couple of things you are naming your DB table column names in camel case which is bad you should be using underscores & as db sqls are generally case insensitive so using `userID` is equivalent to `userid`.

Also you are using `DB::insert` it will not insert any `created_at` or `updated_at` field or other eloquent features so I suggest you insert using `eloquent model` & using relations which is the beauty of laravel & eloquent active records

try like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $role = [];
    $role['role'] = $request->input('role');

    $data= Role::create($role);
    $userdata = User::all();
    $user_id = $userdata->first()->id;
    $id= $data->id;
    DB::table('permissions')->insert([
    'role_id' => $id
    ]);
    DB::table('user_roles')->insert([
    'roleID' => $id,
    'userID' => $user_id
    ]);
   //return $data;
    return redirect(route('allRole'));
}
```

Here `$userdata = User::all();` you are selecting all user do you want all your to have this role then you have to loop through on it & insert it. Or if you want first user to have this role then it's fine.

Also I suggest I think you should read more [Laravels](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2) documentation to clear things.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/03hdQEL6 ,In this way i am trying to get but i get an error ` ErrorException in RoleController.php line 50: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to insert only `roleID` to `user_roles` table.
But within in your given error it seems the `user_roles` TABLE has also `userID` field what is foreign key and connect with `users` (`id`) table.

As `user_roles` is a pivot table and it has both `roleID` and `userID` and both are foreign key. So while inserting with only `roleID` value it's trying to insert the `userID` with the NULL value what is not matched with `user` Table any of IDs that's why Integrity constraint Violated.

So inserting data in a right way would be, you have to provide VALID `userID` as well.

```
$id= $data->id;
DB::table('user_roles')->insert([
'roleID' => $id,
'userID' => $EXISTING_USER_ID 
]);
```

I think, it will solve your problem.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/03hdQEL6 ,In this way i am trying to get but i get an error ` ErrorException in RoleController.php line 50: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id`

Comment: I think, you understand my point perfectly.But how can i get `$EXISTING_USER_ID`. I have tried in first comment way.Please take a look.

Comment: I have seen your pastebin code. you take all user by 
`$userdata = User::all();  $user_id = $userdata->id;` // This line should give error. // 
You have to take only one specific user and take its `id` attribute. 
Like `$userdata = User::all()->first();
$user_id = $userdata->id;`
then try to insert data to `user_roles` table.
And I mean via `$EXISTING_USER_ID` is any user ID which exist in `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

in your above error, you are missing the `userID` field, which is must in relationship perspective. so you should pass the `userID` then your code will be working.

```
$role = [];
$role['role'] = $request->input('role');

$data= Role::create($role);
$id= $data->id;
DB::table('user_roles')->insert([
'roleID' => $id,
'userID'=>1, // pass userID with whom you wan to attach new roleID
]);

return redirect(route('allRole'));
```

**here is advance version of using relationship method**

**Add these method in respective models**

**user model**

```
public function userRoles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','user_roles','userID','roleID');

}
```

**role model**

```
public function roleUsers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_roles','roleID', 'userID');

}
```

and do this for insertion of roles.

```
$user = App\User::find(1);    
$user->roles()->attach($roleId);

$role = [];
$role['role'] = $request->input('role');

$data= Role::create($role);
$id= $data->id;

$user->userRoles()->attach(['
  'roleID' => $id,
  'userID'=>$user->id
']);

return redirect(route('allRole'));
```

Comment: When i am trying to add roles i get error says `Call to a member function roles() on a non-object`.I am puttitng bottom code in RoleController.

Comment: comment out or remove this line `$user->roles()->attach($roleId);`

Comment: Now its shows `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\User' not found`.One things why you use App\User? in attach([
  'roleID' => $id,
  'userID'=>$user->id
]); it will be this you forget to remove single quote between []

Comment: `App\User` is your `User` model. did you added above method in your User and Role Model ?

Comment: Yes i added `use App/User;` in Role model.But i think , it will be `$user = User::find(1);` Am i right?

Comment: if you have written this on top of your class/controller `use App/User;` then you can use  this `$user = User::find(1);`